# Phone still has a value even though I unlinked (firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I used `user.unlinkFromProvider('phone')` to unlink a user's phone account, leaving them with only an email/password account. I looped through `user.providerData` to confirm the only `providerId` are firebase and password. However, printing `user.phoneNumber`, I still see the value of the previously added phone. I'm expecting this value to be null since I've removed/unlinked the phone number.

Comment: Have you tried login in the user in incognito to see if it is present?

Comment: This is for mobile (not web) so I don't think I can login in incognito

Comment: Shoot! Btw, for your use case, there are ways to modify user's Profile. This is for JAVA https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile I am unaware of flutter

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, a simple `user.reload()` will update the user data.

Comment: This has not worked for me (the reload) in the case where the email is linked to phone and email has been unlinked from phone (phone is primary), the email (gmail) remains as part of the identifier. How to I completely remove the email and only remain with the phone as the main identifier?